# Classifying value from input between 3 tables

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have project written in python. I want this program classify fuzzy class from production quantity input, based on three tables in MySQL database.

Here's the tables:

**productions**

| id | year | production_quantity | interval_id | fuzzy_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 274317 | 11 | 6 |
| 2 | 2017 | 200916 | 7 | 3 |
| 3 | 2018 | 217246 | 8 | 4 |
| 4 | 2019 | 119830 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 2020 | 66640 | 1 | 1 |

**interval_fuzzy**

| id | interval_class | left_interval | right_nterval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 65000 | 85000 |
| 2 | A2 | 85000 | 105000 |
| 3 | A3 | 105000 | 125000 |
| 4 | A4 | 125000 | 145000 |
| 5 | A5 | 145000 | 165000 |
| 6 | A6 | 165000 | 185000 |
| 7 | A7 | 185000 | 205000 |
| 8 | A8 | 205000 | 225000 |
| 9 | A9 | 225000 | 245000 |
| 10 | A10 | 245000 | 265000 |
| 11 | A11 | 265000 | 285000 |

**fuzzy_value**

| id | interval_id | forecast_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 75000 |
| 2 | 3 | 75000 |
| 3 | 7 | 215000 |
| 4 | 8 | 115000 |
| 5 | 11 | 275000 |

And the program have a function that shows data.

Show Data

```py
def show_data():
  mycursor.execute("SELECT productions.year, productions.production_quantity, interval_fuzzy.interval_class, fuzzy_value.forecast_value FROM productions INNER JOIN interval_fuzzy ON productions.interval_id = interval_fuzzy.id INNER JOIN fuzzy_value ON productions.fuzzy_id = fuzzy_value.id") 
  myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
  myresult.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
  df = pd.DataFrame(myresult, columns=['Year', 'Production', 'Interval Class', 'Forecast Value'])
  df['Forecast Value'] = df['Forecast Value'].shift(1)
  print(df)
```

And of the output is this

```
    Year  Production  Interval Class  Forecast Value

1   2016      274317             A11          
2   2017      200916              A7          275000
3   2018      217246              A8          215000
4   2019      119830              A3          115000 
5   2020       66640              A1           75000
```

The way Interval Class determined is by looking the `production_quantity` value and classify it between `left_interval` and `right_interval`

Basically what I want is an input function that when I input any new `production_quantity` and `year`, it will automatically classify the `interval_id` and `fuzzy_id` in `productions` table

What kind of function should I create and maybe what should I add to my code?

Answer (score 1):

### Annotated code

```py
# Merge the dataframes to add forecast_value 
# column to productions dataframe
c = ['interval_id', 'forecast_value']
df = productions.merge(fuzzy_value[c], how='left')

# As the intervals are disjoint we can create a IntervalIndex
# from left and right interval columns, then use that to create a mapping series
ix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(interval_fuzzy['left_interval'], 
                                  interval_fuzzy['right_nterval'])
mapping = interval_fuzzy.set_index(ix)['interval_class']

# Use the mapping series to add interval_class based to forecast_value
df['interval_class'] = df['forecast_value'].map(mapping)
```

#### Result

```
   id  year  production_quantity  interval_id  fuzzy_id  forecast_value interval_class
0   1  2016               274317           11         6          275000            A11
1   2  2017               200916            7         3          215000             A8
2   3  2018               217246            8         4          115000             A3
3   4  2019               119830            3         2           75000             A1
4   5  2020                66640            1         1           75000             A1
```